# What does the second argument of tflearn.fully_connected represent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tflearn

I am trying to learn `tflearn`. But I have a few doubts.

In the following line

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
```

is `len(train_x[0])` the shape of my output matrix? If not, what is it?

Second doubt is: what is 8 in this line?

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
```

I tried to search and I found it is `n_units`, but what are they, and how am I supposed to choose how many units I will require in which case?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
```

means that tflearn expects that the input to your network has shape [?, `len(train_x[0])`]. In your case, I think that `train_x` is a matrix, meaning that `len(train_x[0])` would give you the number of columns in your matrix.

If you look at the documentation for tflearns fully connected layer (http://tflearn.org/layers/core/), you will see that the 8 corresponds to the `n_units` argument

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
```

meaning this line will create a fully connected layer with 8 hidden units/neurons.